# hsqldb not working with eclipselink when ddl-generation is create-or-extend-tables

Tags: jakarta-ee, eclipselink, hsqldb

When I set ddl-generation to drop-and-create-tables, everything is fine. But when it is set to create-or-extend-tables, I got this:

```
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: PERSON_ID_SEQ
```

Here is how I set it up:

persistence.xml

```
<persistence ...>
  <persistence-unit name="persistencetest">
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />

      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:test-db" />

      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />

      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-or-extend-tables" />
      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database" />
    </properties>

    <class>test.Person</class>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Person.java

```
@Entity
public class Person
{
  @Id
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "id_seq", sequenceName = "PERSON_ID_SEQ")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "id_seq")
  private long id;

  ...
}
```

pom.xml

```
...
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.extras</groupId>
  <artifactId>glassfish-emdedded-all</artifactId>
  <version>3.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.1</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
  <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.9</version>
</dependency>
...
```

So what is causing create-or-extend-tables to fail while drop-and-create-tables run fine?

Answer (score 0):

Is it an error, or just a warning that is logged?  If no error occurs, it is just a warning, and you can ignore it.  It is just testing to see of the sequence exists.

If an error, include the full exception stack and SQL log.